# How do I make the text in an Entry appear as an * in python (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am making a program that I need the user to enter a password, but I need to know how to make the text in an entry appear as an * so it looks real.

Answer (score 0):

Specify [`show` option](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.config-method) with the character you want to display instead of the characters you typed:

```
from Tkinter import *  # from tkinter import *  in Python 3.x

root = Tk()
Entry(root, show='*').pack()
root.mainloop()
```